# Service worker run event waitUntil() based on some condition

Tags: javascript, service-worker, service-worker-events

I am trying to implement a `cache-then-network` strategy in the service worker which updates the cache in the background. I want to avoid unnecessary `fetch` requests, so came up with the following solution -

```
function cache_then_network(event) {
    var updated = false;
    event.respondWith(
        caches.open(staticCacheName)
            .then(cache => cache.match(event.request)
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response) {
                        return response;
                    }
                    else {
                        return fetch(event.request)
                        .then((response) => {
                            const resClone = response.clone();
                            return caches.open(staticCacheName)
                                .then((cache) => {
                                    cache.put(event.request, response);
                                    updated = true;
                                    return resClone;
                                })
                        })
                    }
                })
            )
    )
    if (!updated) {
        event.waitUntil(update(event.request))
    }
}
```

The `update` function updates the cache by fetching the request using the network.The issue is that the `updated` variable is always false, causing the `update` function to run everytime.

I'm not well versed with service workers, and the code is basically stitched up from multiple sources. So alternative/better solutions are welcome. My ultimate goal is to cache first, fetch from network in background, and set a flag which tells whether the content has changed or not.

Answer (score 0):

The Service worker [offline-cookbook](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook) has all the answers -

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open('mysite-dynamic').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        var fetchPromise = fetch(event.request).then(function(networkResponse) {
          cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());
          return networkResponse;
        })
        return response || fetchPromise;
      })
    })
  );
});
```